# Should we say "Muestra Paul cuando 'fue' más joven" or 'era' for "It shows when Paul was younger"?

Tags: pretérito, pretérito-imperfecto, pretérito-perfecto

> Muestra Paul cuando **fue** más joven.

or

> Muestra Paul cuando **era** más joven.

I want to say, *It shows when Paul was younger*. It's for a tv show which is showing a character from another show but in the past. Would this count as setting the scene or repeated action? I am having trouble telling. Google translate and Spanish checker are telling me to use *era*.

Answer (score 3):

> » *Muestra a Paul cuando **fue** más joven.*
>   (At some definite point in the past, it shows when Paul was younger.)
>
> » *Muestra a Paul cuando **era** más joven.*
>   (During a period of time -unknown- in the past, it shows when Paul was younger.)

The use of *fue* or *era* is not always clear-cut, but we restrict to use the preterite for actions that happened at some definite point in the past.

Comment: That is perfectly correct. The only thing is, he is specifically saying "más joven", which specifies an unspecific past. His example is imperfect, not preterite. _Se nota cuando Paul era más joven._

Comment: @robertotomás Oh! I'll add that, I misread it.

Comment: I have some reservations about this answer. "Muestra a Paul cuando fue más joven" just doesn't sound right. The present perfect could make sense in sentences like "No te olvides de que yo también fui joven", but here the fact of being young lasts a period of time, which is what is being shown. The preterite  ("muestra a Paul cuando *era* más joven") reflects that idea better.

Comment: @Yay I also agree that the former doesn't sound good but I didn't want to dismiss it since perhaps other people may use it. What's the example of the *present perfect* you mean?

Comment: Oops! I meant present simple. I see what you mean. However, it may be useful to make it clearer that, although both are acceptable in different contexts, the preterite is more likely to be the right option here.

Comment: It's actually about the Better Call Saul tv show, to provide context. So it is a series continually set in the past.